# Obtain IP address of wifi connected system

Tags: c#, wifi, ip-address

I am able to achieve Wi-fi communication between android and PC, by hard coding the IP address of the network connected. But i need to get the IP address of the system connected to a wi-fi network. Iam working on windows platform using C#. So please help me in this regard.

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2518155/other-than-udp-broadcast-or-multicast-what-other-methods-can-i-use-on-a-wifi-ne

Answer (score 4):

This may work for you:

```
string[] strIP = null;
int count = 0;

IPHostEntry HostEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()));
if (HostEntry.AddressList.Length > 0)
{
    strIP = new string[HostEntry.AddressList.Length];
    foreach (IPAddress ip in HostEntry.AddressList)
    {
        if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            strIP[count] = ip.ToString();
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, the host could have many IP addresses. This is why the string array is used, it collects them all.

**--EDITED by L.B--**

Here is the the working version of the code above

```
var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntry((Dns.GetHostName()))
                    .AddressList
                    .Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                    .Select(x => x.ToString())
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: `HosyEntry`, use of `strIP` without initializing.  etc. Did you try to compile&run your code?

Comment: yep - sorry. I was away from VS when I wrote this (on my phone). +1 for good edit

Comment: This doesn't get the connected wifi IP address but rather your local machines ip

Answer (score 1):

For UWP, use this to get your local Ip Address. Updated based on answers by @L.B.

```
var addresses = Dns.GetHostEntryAsync((Dns.GetHostName()))
                .Result
                .AddressList
                .Where(x => x.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                .Select(x => x.ToString())
                .ToArray();
```